# Resolving 'Unclosed quotation mark after the character string' on MS SQL Server generated .sql file

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am trying to recreate a remote db on a local SQL Server install. I have a ~(6GB) .sql file generated from the remote db SSMS and am using sqlcmd locally to attempt the import.

Here is the command I am using:

```
sqlcmd -S SERVER -a 32000 -i inputfile.sql -o output.txt
```

Around 2200 records in it gives me: `Unclosed quotation mark after the character string`

Is there something I can do on the import settings (or even create a new exported .sql file) that will resolve this? It's extremely odd that the server generated sql does not appear to be valid sql.

Comment: may be table data have quotes " ' " in it.you can open SQL script in sql studio and check data in it .

Comment: Trying to open the file in SSMS yields a SystemOutOfMemory exception.

Answer (score 10):

This [Stackoverflow thread will prove useful for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695033/sql-server-2008-generate-script-wizard-gives-me-a-script-that-results-in-unclos). Relevant details recreated below:

**Issue description:**

> In some rare cases the sqlcmd utility can fail with
>   the import and raise the following error: "Unclosed quotation mark
>   after the character string ..." which indicates that one of SQL
>   queries has not been executed. This happens because sqlcmd works using
>   stream processing, i.e. it reads some piece of data, processes it,
>   reads next piece and so on. In some cases an input file can contain
>   huge SQL instruction which size is bigger than the amount of the data
>   that could be processed by sqlcmd at a time, so sqlcmd tries to
>   execute broken SQL and fails.

**Possible solution**

> The sqlcmd utility can accept the "-a" parameter which defines the
>   maximum size of packet (piece of data) that will be used during
>   processing. The maximum value is 32767, the default value is 4096, so
>   it makes sense to always use this parameter with maximum value.

```
sqlcmd -i input.sql -a 32767 -o import_log.txt
```

**Alternative solution**

If the above fails for you, you might want to consider using the Bulk Copy (BCP) utility. I believe it is currently the fastest way to move data from a remote source to a local clone or vice versa. You can find more details here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlcat/2010/07/30/loading-data-to-sql-azure-the-fast-way/

```
bcp AdventureWorksLTAZ2008R2.SalesLT.Customer out C:\Users\user\Documents\GetDataFromSQLAzure.txt -c -U username@servername -S tcp:servername.database.windows.net -P password
```

Answer (score 0):

I think jophy job is correct in that there is data with a '.  You might try notepad++ or ultraedit to open it.